# Use ggplot2 to generate histogram from each row of data properly

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a set of data like below:

```
pos A   C   G   T
0   0.291398    0.190061    0.315722    0.202818
1   0.315597    0.227511    0.175448    0.281445
2   0.252149    0.194597    0.222815    0.330438
```

Then I imported the table:

```
library(ggplot2)
d = read.table(tablename, sep = '\t', header = T)
d = d[2:5]
data.frame(t(d))
```

And I got a reformatted table as below:

```
        X1       X2       X3
A 0.291398 0.315597 0.252149
C 0.190061 0.227511 0.194597
G 0.315722 0.175448 0.222815
T 0.202818 0.281445 0.330438
```

However, when I tried to plot it:

```
qplot(X1, data = d, geom = 'histogram')
```

It gives the image below:

[image]

And what I want should be like:(I used libreoffice, so the color and the width and other parameters do not matter)
[image]

May I know how to correct my code to make this shape?
Any help is appreciated. Sorry but I am really new to R and ggplot2.

Comment: You are only plotting one column of your data (i.e. `X1`). That is why each bar is the same height, and along the x-axis at the values in `X1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't telling the plot what you want as your Y value. The X1 choice is the value you got, not the base, and everything is present once, so you get all 1s.

You want X1 as your Y and base as your X.

To fix your plot, from `d`:

```
d$base<-rownames(d)
ggplot(d,aes(x=base,y=X1))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

or using qplot nomenclature:

```
d$base<-rownames(d)
qplot(data = d, x = base, y = X1, geom = 'histogram', stat = "identity")
```

Edit: Here's how I would plot it for all rows:

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- melt(d, id = "pos")
ggplot(d1, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = factor(pos))) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```